# How can I distinguish between supplements and modifiers as proposed in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL)?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, linguistics, modifiers, adjuncts

In CGEL, the authors use the term 'adjunct' as an umbrella term to cover an element that is either modifier or supplement. On page 1350, the authors explain the properties of supplements to distinguish between supplements and modifiers.

[image]
However, these properties are sometimes not reliable (hence, the qualifier phrase at the beginning) because punctuation marks are sometimes used for stylistic reasons.

What I'd like to know is: Because, unlike modifiers, supplements are not integrated into the syntactic construction, does that mean supplements cannot form a constituent with other constituents? If that's the case, can I use constituency tests to distinguish between modifiers and supplements?

Comment: I'd say they are reliable. As your quote says, there are deciding factors other than punctuation. Btw, have you looked at the trees on p1354.

Comment: And plenty of examples of all types are given on pp1356-1361.

Comment: I did look at those trees but the authors said "But the lack of
integration of the supplement into the syntactic structure means that there is no good
reason to treat the supplementation as a syntactic constituent. We propose, therefore,
that in the syntactic representation supplements should be kept separate from the tree" (p. 1353).  So they propose those trees after deciding that supplements are not integrated into the syntactic structure. I just want to know what they mean by "not integrated into the syntactic structure"? Do they mean "not forming constituent with other constituents?"

Comment: *I just want to know what they mean by "not integrated into the syntactic structure"?* -- As I understand it, they mean "do not form part of the idea contained within the basic main clause of a sentence." -- e.g. "By the way, I hit him." / I, by the way, hit him." / "I hit him, by the way." -- Here "by the way" (or "for your information", etc.) is not integrated into the sentence. It is a separate idea in its own right - almost an interjection.

Comment: What they call "supplements" can often be constituents. There are reliable syntactic tests for constituency; there are not for supplementarity, or complementarity.

Comment: No: the whole point about supplements is that they are not constituents. This obviously means that they do not combine with other elements to form larger constituents. How much clearer can it be?

Comment: @BillJ I agree with you. The authors said in the quote above that they are not constituents. Also, one of the authors (Rodney Huddleston) explained in his older book that "Constituent' is a relational concept: if x is a constituent, it must be a constituent of something" (Huddleston, 1984, p. 3).  It follows that supplements do not form a larger constituent with other constituents.

Thank you guys very much for the input!

Comment: There still is no Answer is the Answer Box.